# Custom Boostrap 4 Spacing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add more sizes to the $spacers Sass map variable but it doesn't work. Based on the Bootstrap 4 [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) I should just be able to do something like this:

```
  $spacer: 1rem !default;
  $spacers: (
  0: 0,
  1: ($spacer * .25),
  2: ($spacer * .5),
  3: $spacer,
  4: ($spacer * 1.5),
  5: ($spacer * 3),
  6: ($spacer * 5)
) !default;
```

This is the custom line I've added `6: ($spacer * 5)`

Comment: Are you including the containing sass file before or after to bootstrap file with the same variable?

Comment: @JosephMarikle I edited the Bootstrap _variables.scss itself. In this case, does the order matter?

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters in this case, but the `!default` is there so you can create your own, minimal `_variables.scss` file that you include before the bootstrap files.  It overrides the later declaration.  `!default` causes the declaration to check if the variable has already been declared before.  If it has, it skips the later one.

Comment: I can't see anything in the bootstrap files shat would prevent the sixth spacer from being added.  I would discourage you from modifying the Bootstrap `_variables.scss` file directly, but doing so should work anyway.  What are the contents of your bootstrap sass file? (That's not to be confused with "Bootstrap". I want to know the contents of the initial file you compile with sass.)

Comment: @JosephMarikle I think I know what the problem is. The app that I'm using (Prepros) doesn't compile Bootstrap files and therefore whatever I do in the .scss file doesn't get translated into the Bootstrap CSS. Any simple suggestions on how to compile it?

Comment: It's probably in how the bootstrap css is included.  Can you find where in your project the `<link>` for bootstrap is included?  What path does it use to link to it?  You're going to need to probably remove that, and instead manually add the includes to your initial sass file that kicks off the includes for your project.  It would help to have the folder structure too.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I finally got it working. I created a `_spacing.scss` file in my project directory, imported it in the main `_styles.scss` and then imported `_bootstrap.scss` into `_spacing.scss`. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

> Are you including the containing sass file before or after to bootstrap file with the same variable?

This hint fixed it for me - putting the $spacers map declarations in my own _variables.scss before the bootstrap sass files where included. Thanks!